# Como usar o time_format() no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Fiz uma tabela assim:

```
create table tabela (
hora time not null
);
```

Essa tabela me retorna hora, minuto e segundo. Como fica a tabela com o time_format()? Quero deixá-la só com a hora e o segundo. Minha dúvida é na sintaxe (maneira de montar o time).

Valor retornado: 00:00:00.
Valor que eu quero que retorne: 00:00.

Motivo: eu tô capturando o horário de um formulário HTML (00:00) e salvando no banco de dados. Quando o horário é enviado do formulário para o banco de dados, o banco de dados o armazena assim: 00:00:00. Por isso eu quero que, na hora da criação da tabela, o time aceite este formato: 00:00.

Comment: Hora e segundo mesmo? ou seria hora e minuto?

Comment: Quero somente a hora e o minuto.

Answer (score 3):

O `time_format()` recebe primeiro o campo e depois os parâmetros de formatação, para exibir hora e segundo ficaria assim:

```
select TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H:%s') from tabela
```

Por via das dúvidas, segue também como exibir hora e minutos:

```
select TIME_FORMAT(hora, '%H:%i') from tabela
```

Coloquei no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/356e1f/10) para referencia futura

Comment: Dúvido que seja Hora:Segundo :)

Comment: Também acho, coloquei os dois formatos para garantir

Comment: Mas eu não quero o select, quero a sintaxe quando se cria na tabela.

Comment: @WillBill, desculpa, não ficou claro qual sua dúvida quanto a montar a tabela, o tipo `time` já é hora, minuto e segundo

Comment: @Barbetta, pois é, eu quero que o time seja só hora e minuto. Não quero no select, e sim quando se cria o time na tabela.

Comment: pelo que entendi você deseja que a tabela seja apenas hora e minuto(00:00), a primeiro momento, o que me vem a cabeça é salvar o campo como `varchar`.

Comment: Mas será que não tem como tirar os segundos na hora da criação?

Comment: Fiz uma pesquisa rápida aqui e não achei nada indicando que é possível fazer isso, talvez esse [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-time/) e esse outro [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html)  possam te ajudar